# Get an array using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I used to use JSTL java tags like this.

Basically this would create many inputs per day for each clientType.

```
<form method="post">
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${amountOfDayEnds}" varStatus="day">
            <tr class="text-center hover-table">
                <td>${day.count}</td>
                <c:forEach var="clientType" items="${clientTypes}">
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <input class='text-center field' value='0' type='number' data-validation='[V>=0,INTEGER]' data-validation-message='Only integer numbers equal or greater than 0 allowed.'
                                name='dataClients[]' min='0' required/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</form>
```

And I would get the data in jquery using `var data = $('form').serialize();`

How would I do this using Angular? I'm using Angular 6.

Comment: Are you sure this is Angular 6? This is not Angular's template syntax. By the way, there is no need to use jQuery. You should use data-binding, or ReactiveForms to accomplish this.

Comment: I had this code using java. but now I'm using angular

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming you are trying to convert this to Angular. You need to use **ngFor**. For an introduction to this check the [Displaying a List](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2) page in the Angular Tutorial.

Basically, it is going to end up looking something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <div *ngFor="let day of days">
        <tr class="text-center hover-table">
            {{day | json}}
```

Comment: where are the inputs? And how do I get the values of the inputs?